# Reusing Web Service classes in client

Tags: java, web-services, wsimport

Basic idea:
I have 2 servers. Each one has web service and data collection servlet. Servlet in server A collects data from web service in server B and vice versa.

Now I do "wsimport", and use generated classes in sevlet. I don't like it. Same class names, every time I modify ws method name or parameter, I must repeat wsimport etc.

Basically, I have WS source code / address. I want call remote WS methods from servlet. Can I do that?

Comment: can u please be a little more specific , this seems a little confusing ,tell us what you have and what you want ???

Comment: I have web service source. Can I somehow construct WS object and call its methods from servlet?

Comment: Now I generate client classes with wsimport

Comment: you might already be calling the web service through the URL , simply write a java class to call appropriate web service according to the parameter , just pass the method name , thus you dont have to write all the configuration , btw we have a remote function concept which i will let you know asap

Comment: @bigGuy, sure you can. You'll only have to deal with all the XML plumbing yourself, which by itself defeats the objective you're trying to achieve, because any changes to the service will still result in a change to the client. I'd advise you design the webservice to be more generic so that changes won't necessarily affect the client